# datenum gives different values same date-time?

Tags: matlab

When I convert given date-number '2011-01-06 0:45' by

```
datenum('2011-01-06 0:45','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM')
```

I get

```
734509.0313
```

as date-number.

But when I generate a vector of date-numbers using

```
begin_date_time=datenum('2011-01-06 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
str_next_date=strcat('2011-01-06',32,'00:15:00');
next_date_time=datenum(str_next_date,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
interval=next_date_time-begin_date_time;
end_date_time=datenum('2011-12-31 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
full_data_time_steps=begin_date_time:interval:end_date_time;
```

The fourth date-number in the vector 'full_data_time_steps' is

```
734509.0312.
```

But it corresponds to the same date-time '2011-01-06 0:45'. I am not sure why this is happening and how to solve this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is `time_scale{ind_node}`?

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more specific. In this case, it was 15 (minutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you are looking at them correctly? When I do

```
format long g % to make sure we see all the decimals 

datenum('2011-01-06 0:45','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM')

ans =

              734509.03125

begin_date_time=datenum('2011-01-06 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
str_next_date=strcat('2011-01-06',32,'00:15:00');
next_date_time=datenum(str_next_date,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
interval=next_date_time-begin_date_time;
end_date_time=datenum('2011-12-31 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS');
full_data_time_steps=begin_date_time:interval:end_date_time;
full_data_time_steps(4)

ans =

              734509.03125
```

I get the same.

Comment: Yeah. When I do 
     intersect(full_data_time_steps,datenum('2011-01-06 0:45','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM')).

I get empty matrix. They look same after rounding off.

Comment: @AbhinavGupta you are right, they are `datenum('2011-01-06 0:45','yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM')-full_data_time_steps(4) = 1.16415321826935e-10` in difference, however that is withing floating point accuracy (in fact just there). You may want to [read more about comparing floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686439/why-is-24-0000-not-equal-to-24-0000-in-matlab)

Comment: @AbhinavGupta consider accepting the answer as valid if it helped you.